# How to find out the PIN number of a smart card

Tags: java

I am beginner in smart card authentication area. I have a smart card for my project purpose, how can i get the unique PIN number of that smart card using java code. I don't have any idea about this.can anyone help me to find this..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a random number generator program and store each random number generated in a database. Every time you generate a random number, please check whether the number generated is already present in the data base or not. If the random number generated is not present in DB then well and good. If it is already present in the data base increment/decrement the number by some value and provide the random number.

Comment: Can you please explain how this comment related to smart card?

Answer (score 0):

The pin should be set to a manufacturer preset from where you bought the SmartCard from. I'd recommend contacting the manufacturer.

There is no way to pull a pin from a SmartCard as this would make a pin useless for security purposes and ruin the 2-factor authentication which SmartCards are used for (something physical and something you know aka the SmartCard and the pin)

Normal practices are once the certs are loaded onto a SmartCard then the pin is changed to a something the end user knows.